# How to remove xml tag using as3

Tags: xml, regex, actionscript-3

I have exported data  .xls file using as3.

```
var xml:ArrayCollection;
xml=Labneuron8.lastResult.Response.Terminal as ArrayCollection;
var str:String=xml[0].Value;
var xml1:XML=new XML(str);
myData=new XMLListCollection(xml1.children());
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString());
var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
f.save(bytes,"output.xls");
```

while running a .xls file is created with values

```
<Val>0.307280</Val>
<Val>0.307280</Val>
<Val>0.307280</Val>
<Val>0.307280</Val>
<Val>0.307280</Val>
<Val>0.307280</Val> .......
```

Now I have to delete this Val tags, which is not required.

Please let me know script to delete this tag.

Thanks
.............UPDATE................

Now I modified the code as

```
var xml:ArrayCollection;
xml=Labneuron8.lastResult.Response.Terminal as ArrayCollection;
var str:String=xml[0].Value;
var xml1:XML=new XML(str);
var vals:XMLList = xml1.Val;
for each(var val:XML in vals)
    {
        delete (val.parent().children()[val.childIndex()]);
        Alert.show("hi");
    }
myData=new XMLListCollection(xml1.children());
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString());
var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
f.save(bytes,"output.xls");
```

But the for each loop is not working.So I get the same output as before with val tags.How this can be solved?
To delete an xml nodes, first you need to find them:

```
var sourceXML:XML = ...
var vals:XMLList = sourceXML.Val; //enter actual path to Val nodes here
```

Then you delete each one using parent:

```
for each(var val:XML in vals)
{
    delete (val.parent().children()[val.childIndex()]);
}
```

If all your nodes have same parent, you can cache val.parent().children() in local variable, so it will be faster.

..................UPDATE...................

@Patrick

```
var xml:ArrayCollection;

xml=Labneuron8.lastResult.Response.Terminal as ArrayCollection;

var str:String=xml[0].Value;

var xml1:XML=new XML(str);

xml1..Val.(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex(),valueOf().text()))

myData=new XMLListCollection(xml1.children());

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString());

var f:FileReference = new FileReference();

f.save(bytes,"output.xls");
```

...............SOLUTION ....................

```
var xml6:ArrayCollection;

xml6=Labneuron8.lastResult.Response.Terminal as ArrayCollection;

var str:String=xml6[0].Value;   

var xml1:XML=new XML(str);

xml1..Val.(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex(),valueOf().text()+"\n"))

myData3=new XMLListCollection(xml1.children());

var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

bytes.writeObject(myData3.children().toString());

var fo:FileReference = new FileReference();

fo.save(bytes,"output.xls");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i think i have understand what you want , you don't want to delete the Val node but only replace it with it's content.

So you can do it like that using the replace function if your parent node have only one children:

in one line:

```
xml1..Val.(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex(), valueOf().text()))
```

or with a loop:

```
for each (var val:XML in xml1..Val) {
 val.parent().replace(val.childIndex(), val.toString())
}
```

---

Added a live example to show how the delete works:
http://wonderfl.net/c/fHph

You can do it also in one line as this:

```
//...

var xml1:XML=new XML(str);
xml1.Val.(delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]) 

//...
```

If you want to delete **all Val** node wherever they are use `..` notation

```
//...

var xml1:XML=new XML(str);
xml1..Val.(delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]) 

//...
```

Comment: @Mithula P Sreedharan i have added a working sample to see that works

Comment: +1 Nice example. In xml selector any code can be executed and valueOf() gets current node. I'll learn this trick for myself :3

Comment: @patrick Thanks for such an  example.In this live example after this instruction  xml1..Val.(delete parent().children()[valueOf().childIndex()]) trace results array and dbl only,not val.But I get a blank xls without the numerical value  .It should retain that numerical value.

Comment: @Mithula P Sreedharan ok i think i have understand what you want, i have updated the answer.

Comment: @Patrick...Now I tried this script as per the live example. xml1..Val.(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex,valueOf().text())), bytes.writeObject(xml1.toXMLString()); it now generate <Array2><DBL>  <Val>0.307602</Val></DBL>.......<Array2>.I need xls with only 0.307602,0.307602 etc only

Comment: @Patrick I tried this script also  xml1..Val(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex,valueOf().text()))
Alert.show("xml1"+xml1..Val(parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex,valueOf().text())));
bytes.writeObject(xml1..Val.parent().replace(valueOf().childIndex,valueOf().text())));
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var f:FileReference = new FileReference();
f.save(bytes,"output.xls");It alerts 
<Val>0.310179</Val><Val>0.310179</Val>
<Val>0.307602</Val>
<Val>0.305991</Val>and generates a blank xls file.

Comment: @Mithula P Sreedharan it's childIndex() not childIndex

Comment: @Patrick  oops!! I forgot to add parenthesis.Now I got xls with numeric value only.Thank you so much.But the whole values are in a single row like 6029580.7810740.6992630.4493210.2728160.1668490.1220780.116602....How can I make it in column wise.Is it possible to add new line property after each value?Now the final code is edited above.

Answer (score 4):

To delete an xml nodes, first you need to find them:

```
var sourceXML:XML = ...
var vals:XMLList = sourceXML.Val; //enter actual path to Val nodes here
```

Then you delete each one using parent:

```
for each(var val:XML in vals)
{
    delete (val.parent().children()[val.childIndex()]);
}
```

If all your nodes have same parent, you can cache val.parent().children() in local variable, so it will be faster.

Comment: This must be because Val tags aren't selected with `xml1.Vals` and `vals` is empty. Show the structure of your xml file.

Comment: xml tree is like 
<Array2>
<DBL>
<Val>0.302770</Val>By using bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString()); i can omit upto DBL tag
</DBL>
<DBL>
<Val>0.302126</Val>
</DBL>
<DBL>
<Val>0.301804</Val>
</DBL>
........
<Val>0.303737</Val>
</DBL>
</Array2>By using bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString());I can omit upto DBL tag

Comment: Then select nodes like `var vals:XMLList = xml1.DBL.Val;` - this will leave empty DBL tags; or like `var vals:XMLList = xml1.DBL;` - this will remove DBL tags.

Comment: bytes.writeObject(myData.children().toString()); results <Val>0.3037</Val> this Val tag only .not DBL.So I used var vals:XMLList = xml1.Val;If I use var vals:XMLList = xml1.DBL.Val;or var vals:XMLList = xml1.DBL the generated xls will not contains any data.

Answer (score 1):

To get the internal value of xml-nodes you can (sometimes) use: nodeValue.

example:

```
rootNode.childNodes[a].nodeValue
```

This will "delete"/does not return the xml-tag. I've used it in a AS2 project, and I'm not sure if nodeValue is still accepted in AS3.

Comment: While you can use nodeValue() in E4X to get current node in selector, I don't see how this can delete anything.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase then, ... it doesn't delete anything, however it does not return the xml-tag